# How to add if condition inside the anchor tag in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

We have reactjs application. We are passing one 'text' to one function. Inside that function, we have anchor tag. Here, i have to write if condition to check if the text is empty. If it is empty then we have to add aria-lable otherwise, just return the text.

Comment: Please add some code example, to clarify your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `if-else` is not supported inside a tag or a component in React. You can use ternary operator or you can add props conditionally instead.

See the examples below:

```
<a aria-label={text === '' ? 'your-aria-label-here' : ''}>
  {text}
</a>
```

Or

```
<a
   {...(text === '' && {
     'aria-label': 'your-aria-label-here',
   })}
>
  {text}
</a>
```

~Prayag

Comment: It worked , Thank you.. Can you please explain the second one?

Comment: In the second option, I'm assigning the prop conditionally. If the condition is false, the prop won't be there itself instead of having the value `''`.

Answer (score 0):

use ternary oprator

```
(text === '') ? "Value if true" : "Value if false"
```

example

```
let link = (<a key={key} className={classname} href={'#'} aria-label={...(text) ? "true" : text }> Heelo </a>);
```

Comment: remember to add braces `{text === '' ? "do something" : "do something"}`

Comment: I tired it. But inside the anchor it is giving error. After href i added the condition like this, it didn't work

let link = ( <a key={} className={)} href={} {(text==='') ? 'label' :text} >{text}</a>);

Comment: can you add you code (function) snippet to clarify your issue

Comment: let link = ( <a key={} className={)} href={} );